# issue with calculating accuracy

Tags: pytorch, metrics, torch, pytorch-lightning

i'm using Torch Metrics to try to calculate the accuracy of my model. But i'm getting this error. I tried using `.to(device="cuda:0")` but I got a cuda initialization error. I also tried using `.cuda()` but that didn't work either. I'm using PyTorch lightning with a Titan Xp GPU. Im using a mish activation function with the Movie-lens data set.

code:

```
# %% [markdown]
# # Data Preprocessing
# 
# Before we start building and training our model, let's do some preprocessing to get the data in the required format.

# %% [code] {"_kg_hide-input":true,"_kg_hide-output":true}
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch.nn.functional as F
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import wandb
import torchmetrics

wandb.init(project="Mocean-Recommendor",entity="maxall4")

config = wandb.config


def mish(x):
    return (x*torch.tanh(F.softplus(x)))


np.random.seed(123)

# %% [markdown]
# First, we import the ratings dataset.

# %% [code]
ratings = pd.read_csv('rating.csv', 
                      parse_dates=['timestamp'])

# %% [markdown]
# In order to keep memory usage manageable within Kaggle's kernel, we will only use data from 30% of the users in this dataset. Let's randomly select 30% of the users and only use data from the selected users.

# %% [code]
rand_userIds = np.random.choice(ratings['userId'].unique(), 
                                size=int(len(ratings['userId'].unique())*0.3), 
                                replace=False)

ratings = ratings.loc[ratings['userId'].isin(rand_userIds)]

print('There are {} rows of data from {} users'.format(len(ratings), len(rand_userIds)))

# %% [code]
ratings.sample(5)

# %% [code]
ratings['rank_latest'] = ratings.groupby(['userId'])['timestamp'] \
                                .rank(method='first', ascending=False)

train_ratings = ratings[ratings['rank_latest'] != 1]
test_ratings = ratings[ratings['rank_latest'] == 1]

# drop columns that we no longer need
train_ratings = train_ratings[['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']]
test_ratings = test_ratings[['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']]

# %% [markdown]
# ### Converting the dataset into an implicit feedback dataset


# %% [code]
train_ratings.loc[:, 'rating'] = 1

train_ratings.sample(5)

# %% [markdown]
# The code below generates 4 negative samples for each row of data. In other words, the ratio of negative to positive samples is 4:1. This ratio is chosen arbitrarily but I found that it works rather well (feel free to find the best ratio yourself!)

# %% [code]
# Get a list of all movie IDs
all_movieIds = ratings['movieId'].unique()

# Placeholders that will hold the training data
users, items, labels = [], [], []

# This is the set of items that each user has interaction with
user_item_set = set(zip(train_ratings['userId'], train_ratings['movieId']))

# 4:1 ratio of negative to positive samples
num_negatives = 4

for (u, i) in tqdm(user_item_set):
    users.append(u)
    items.append(i)
    labels.append(1) # items that the user has interacted with are positive
    for _ in range(num_negatives):
        # randomly select an item
        negative_item = np.random.choice(all_movieIds) 
        # check that the user has not interacted with this item
        while (u, negative_item) in user_item_set:
            negative_item = np.random.choice(all_movieIds)
        users.append(u)
        items.append(negative_item)
        labels.append(0) # items not interacted with are negative


# %% [code]
class MovieLensTrainDataset(Dataset):
    """MovieLens PyTorch Dataset for Training
    
    Args:
        ratings (pd.DataFrame): Dataframe containing the movie ratings
        all_movieIds (list): List containing all movieIds
    
    """

    def __init__(self, ratings, all_movieIds):
        self.users, self.items, self.labels = self.get_dataset(ratings, all_movieIds)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.users)
  
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.users[idx], self.items[idx], self.labels[idx]

    def get_dataset(self, ratings, all_movieIds):
        users, items, labels = [], [], []
        user_item_set = set(zip(ratings['userId'], ratings['movieId']))

        num_negatives = 4
        for u, i in user_item_set:
            users.append(u)
            items.append(i)
            labels.append(1)
            for _ in range(num_negatives):
                negative_item = np.random.choice(all_movieIds)
                while (u, negative_item) in user_item_set:
                    negative_item = np.random.choice(all_movieIds)
                users.append(u)
                items.append(negative_item)
                labels.append(0)

        return torch.tensor(users), torch.tensor(items), torch.tensor(labels)


# %% [code]
acc_metric = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
class NCF(pl.LightningModule):
    """ Neural Collaborative Filtering (NCF)
    
        Args:
            num_users (int): Number of unique users
            num_items (int): Number of unique items
            ratings (pd.DataFrame): Dataframe containing the movie ratings for training
            all_movieIds (list): List containing all movieIds (train + test)
    """
    
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_items, ratings, all_movieIds):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=num_users, embedding_dim=8)
        self.item_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=num_items, embedding_dim=8)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32)
        self.output = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=1)
        self.ratings = ratings
        self.all_movieIds = all_movieIds
    
    def on_validation_end(self,outputs):
        loss = torch.stack([x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
        return { 'loss' : loss }    
    def forward(self, user_input, item_input):
        
        # Pass through embedding layers
        user_embedded = self.user_embedding(user_input)
        item_embedded = self.item_embedding(item_input)

        # Concat the two embedding layers
        vector = torch.cat([user_embedded, item_embedded], dim=-1)

        # Pass through dense layer
        vector = mish(self.fc1(vector))
        vector = mish(self.fc2(vector))

        # Output layer
        pred = nn.Sigmoid()(self.output(vector))

        return pred
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        user_input, item_input, labels = batch
        predicted_labels = self(user_input, item_input)
        loss = nn.BCELoss()(predicted_labels, labels.view(-1, 1).float())

        acc = acc_metric(predicted_labels,labels)

        wandb.log({"loss": loss,"acc":acc})
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters())

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(MovieLensTrainDataset(self.ratings, self.all_movieIds),
                          batch_size=512, num_workers=4)

# %% [markdown]
# We instantiate the NCF model using the class that we have defined above.

# %% [code]
num_users = ratings['userId'].max()+1
num_items = ratings['movieId'].max()+1

all_movieIds = ratings['movieId'].unique()

model = NCF(num_users, num_items, train_ratings, all_movieIds)


# %% [code]
wandb.watch(model)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
        monitor='loss',
        min_delta=0.00,
        patience=3,
        verbose=False,
        mode='min',
    )

trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=100, gpus=1, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=True,
                     progress_bar_refresh_rate=50, logger=False, checkpoint_callback=True,callbacks=[early_stopping])

trainer.fit(model)


# %% [markdown]
# ### Hit Ratio @ 10 

# %% [code]
# User-item pairs for testing
test_user_item_set = set(zip(test_ratings['userId'], test_ratings['movieId']))

# Dict of all items that are interacted with by each user
user_interacted_items = ratings.groupby('userId')['movieId'].apply(list).to_dict()

hits = []
for (u,i) in tqdm(test_user_item_set):
    interacted_items = user_interacted_items[u]
    not_interacted_items = set(all_movieIds) - set(interacted_items)
    selected_not_interacted = list(np.random.choice(list(not_interacted_items), 99))
    test_items = selected_not_interacted + [i]
    
    predicted_labels = np.squeeze(model(torch.tensor([u]*100), 
                                        torch.tensor(test_items)).detach().numpy())
    
    top10_items = [test_items[i] for i in np.argsort(predicted_labels)[::-1][0:10].tolist()]
    
    if i in top10_items:
        hits.append(1)
    else:
        hits.append(0)
        
print("The Hit Ratio @ 10 is {:.2f}".format(np.average(hits)))
wandb.log({"hit ratio": np.average(hits)})
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 359, in <module>
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=100, gpus=1, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=True,
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 499, in fit
    self.dispatch()
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 546, in dispatch
    self.accelerator.start_training(self)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 73, in start_training
    self.training_type_plugin.start_training(trainer)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py", line 114, in start_training
    self._results = trainer.run_train()
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 637, in run_train
    self.train_loop.run_training_epoch()
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 492, in run_training_epoch
    batch_output = self.run_training_batch(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 654, in run_training_batch
    self.optimizer_step(optimizer, opt_idx, batch_idx, train_step_and_backward_closure)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 425, in optimizer_step
    model_ref.optimizer_step(
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 1390, in optimizer_step
    optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 214, in step
    self.__optimizer_step(*args, closure=closure, profiler_name=profiler_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 134, in __optimizer_step
    trainer.accelerator.optimizer_step(optimizer, self._optimizer_idx, lambda_closure=closure, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 277, in optimizer_step
    self.run_optimizer_step(optimizer, opt_idx, lambda_closure, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 282, in run_optimizer_step
    self.training_type_plugin.optimizer_step(optimizer, lambda_closure=lambda_closure, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py", line 163, in optimizer_step
    optimizer.step(closure=lambda_closure, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 66, in step
    loss = closure()
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 648, in train_step_and_backward_closure
    result = self.training_step_and_backward(
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 742, in training_step_and_backward
    result = self.training_step(split_batch, batch_idx, opt_idx, hiddens)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 293, in training_step
    training_step_output = self.trainer.accelerator.training_step(args)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 156, in training_step
    return self.training_type_plugin.training_step(*args)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py", line 125, in training_step
    return self.lightning_module.training_step(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 318, in training_step
    print(type(labels))
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py", line 152, in forward
    self.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py", line 199, in wrapped_func
    return update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchmetrics/classification/accuracy.py", line 142, in update
    self.correct += correct
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

Comment: Try printing this:

print(next(model.parameters()).device)

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer i got ```cpu```

Comment: In this line try to set GPUs to None just for testing, and tell if it is working or not,

trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=100, gpus=None, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=True,
                     progress_bar_refresh_rate=50, logger=False, checkpoint_callback=True,callbacks=[early_stopping])

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer Setting GPUs to None fixed it.

Comment: There is a good thing and a bad thing in this, good thing is your program will work, but the bad thing is your program will only work on CPU, will not use GPU. Are you okay with it ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer it's not ideal seeing as with the full dataset it will take 48 hours per epoch. But can you explain why it wont run on the GPU.

Comment: Can you also print this:  print(next(model.parameters()).is_cuda)

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer i got ```False```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am explaining it here,

This command:

```
print(next(model.parameters()).device)
```

It will print the device on which your model's parameters are loaded.

To check if they are loaded on GPU or not, you can do this:

```
print(next(model.parameters()).is_cuda)
```

It will return a boolean value,

After seeing your code, and as you mentioned it was returning "CPU" when printed:
**next(model.parameters()).device**

Means that your model's parameter are loaded on CPU, but this line

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=100, gpus=1, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=True,
                 progress_bar_refresh_rate=50, logger=False, checkpoint_callback=True,callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Here **gpus=1** means it will set the number of gpus to train,
since all your tensors are loaded on by default **CPU**, you were getting that error.

When you have set **gpus=None** it is no more using gpus to train.

To run on GPUs:

You have to move tensors from CPU to GPU,

For example:

```
ex_tensor=torch.zeros((7,7))
ex_tensor = ex_tensor.cuda()
```

And also your parameters of the model,

```
model = model.cuda()
```

Comment: I moved the tensors and the model parameters to the gpu. But i get a Cuda initialization error.

Comment: @maxall4
In this function :

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(MovieLensTrainDataset(self.ratings, self.all_movieIds),
                          batch_size=512, num_workers=4)

can you set num_workers=0, is it working after setting it to 0.

Comment: When i set the num_workers=0 i get this error: RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!

Comment: Here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/mcEeMz5M

Comment: Can you please change it to: model = model.cuda()

Comment: changing it to ```model = model.cuda()``` still doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell me which line is exactly giving this error, when you run the script ?

Comment: it is 
trainer.fit(model)

Comment: Here is the full error: https://pastebin.com/rie3TwAN

Comment: Can you remove GPUs=1 from trainer and then run the script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232013/discussion-between-knowledgegainer-and-maxall4).